# Variants to place sub in car

Tags: suzuki, audio, grand-vitara

I have Suzuki Grand Vitara 2013. I want to place a sub inside it. But I havn't got a lot of space in trunk, because of GBE. [image: Trunk]

I've bought Rockville RW10CA 10" 800 Watt Under-Seat Slim Amplified Car Subwoofer, to solve the problem with space. But I'm not sure it is a good idea to place it under the seat. Is it comfortable to sit above sub?

The second variant I have, it is to place sub at the trunk door. [image: Trunk door] Is this a good idea? I'm afraid that the trunk door will vibrate a lot.

Maybe I have other variants?

Comment: Try sitting on it and see what you think - 2 minutes of good bass music should give you sufficient evidence....

Comment: The sub you bought is supposed to go under the passenger seat. Also when driving around with the sub the vibration it creates dissapears by road bumps etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I placed this sub under the front passenger sit. There is a vibration, but it is not significant.